# Range of Subset of Population based on a Sample

Tags: sample, roc, range

Suppose I have a population with a known mean, range, and variance of a characteristic $v$. I am producing sets from this population that are of negligible size compared to the size of the population. I sample each of these sets and measure $v$ on each of my samples. Let's say the size of the set is $N$, and I take $n$ samples. What can I infer, with some confidence interval, about the attributes of the subset of $N$ units of the population using the data on the $n$ samples I took?

To put it into a more digestible form, say I am a pharmaceutical company making lots of pills. I know the attributes of the entire population because I've done a lot of testing before I brought them to market (the mean, range, and variance of the population are known). I put $N$ pills into each bottle, and I want to test $n$ pills from each bottle. What can I say about the mean, range, and variance of the subset of pills I have in that bottle based on the $n$ samples I took from it?

As far as I can tell, this is a more granular form of operating characteristics (OC curves) because I don't just want to set the probability of accepting the bottle. Or rather, I do want to set the probability of accepting the bottle *based on* the range that bottle can contain. I'm not quite sure how to translate OC curves into actual values. The attributes of the subset of $N$ units can be estimated using $n$ samples (I am fairly sure - I am not very experienced in statistics) but I want to leverage my knowledge about the population to help narrow down the range. Is there a way to do this?